# Сделать 4 разных колонки?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, vuetify

Есть 4 адаптивных колонки
Это конечно круто, но как мне сделать 4 разных колонки по 200px (разный контент)

```
      <v-container fluid>
    <p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
    <v-row>
      <v-col
        v-for="n in 4"
        :key="n"
        cols="12"
        sm="3"
      >
        <v-card
          class="pa-2"
          outlined
          tile
        >
          One of three columns
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>

    <nuxt />
  </v-container>
```

Comment: Убрать `props'ы` связанные с сеткой(колонками) и привязать свой класс где `width: 200px`.

Comment: конкретней ????

Answer (score 0):

Получается, что каждая твоя колонка имеет cols='12', а тебе надо сделать cols='3', чтобы они в строку помещались.